# CALCULATING stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

How can I calculate  the stochastic integral $I_T (X)$ for all $T ∈ [0, ∞)$ of the stochastic process
$$X_T = 5 × 1_{[0,3]} + \sin(W_2) × 1_{(3,7]} + \cos(W_7) × 1_{(7,8]}?$$

Here $W_2$ and $W_7$ are the values of Wiener Processes at $T=2$ and $T=7$, respectively.

Anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: It's an elementary process, so just use the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The expression for $X_t$ is correct? It doesn't depend on $t$.